# Python integration error

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone know why I get an error here. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

ang=np.linspace(0,180,180)
y=np.linspace(0,100,180)
x=np.cos(3.14*ang/180)

for j in range(180):
   norf=integrate.trapz(y[j],x)
```

The error is: **list assignment index out of range**

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to iterate over a numpy array:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

ang = np.linspace(0, 180, 180)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 180)
x = np.cos(3.14 * ang / 180)

norf = integrate.trapz(y, x)
norf
```

#### output:

```
-100.05059330254954
```

Comment: Thank you Reblochon, but I need to integrate each element in y over x, so my output should have the length of y

Comment: Your integral is the sum of these elements.